# Object detection noise filtering

Tags: object-detection, yolo

In my project, I am detecting only one class, which is "airplane", using yolov5. However, at some frames, the neural network labels some of the buildings as airplanes, which obviously are not. This noise happens like 1 frame among 60 frames. How should I treat this issue? Which algorithms can be applied to filter out?

Comment: I had a similar issue with faces detection and Yolo. The best solution from an accuracy standpoint was in adding simple classification network for 2 classes 0-not a face and 1 -face. And passing resized block detected by you to double-check by this net. It perfectly filters almost all Yolo's false detections. Please let me know if you consider it can suit your case - I can share more details.

Comment: Hello @StepanNovikov actually I think this is what I need. Best way to see that is to test and see I believe. I trained my object detection yolov5 with the repository ```https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5```. I might be wrong but what you means is adding some extra layers at the end of yolov5 network,right?

Comment: Can you please rephrase this sentence "However, at some frames network boxes, some of the building around my perspective which obviously not an airplane." so that it is clear? What does "frames network boxes" mean? Then you say "some of the building around my perspective", what your perspective?

Comment: however at some of the frames, network tags some of the buildings as ```airplane``` which they are not. @nbro. Stepan understood btw.

Comment: @BerkantAy I am not sure how Stephan understood, but I didn't and my supposed job (according to me) is to make this community great and all the posts understandable to all users, including myself. Anyway, so, are you saying that your neural network detects some buildings as airplanes, every 1 over 60 frames/images? So, I suppose, you're trying to perform object detection on a video. Is this right? And what is the noise here? Is the noise the wrong detection? That's not noise, but your neural network performing bad.

Comment: It was an additional ANN simple classifier trained to determine if given input picture is a face or not. Just 2-3 conv layers + 2-3 MLP layers with SoftMax for 2 classes (for better accuracy). After you have this ANN trained, you need to verify boxes detected by Yolo if it really aircrafts or false detection by resizing detected box to the input of your checking ANN  and checking by it. In my case with faces I was able to get rid of majority false detected faces by Yolo. I guess it's better to create an answer with samples and links than continue here. Please confirm understanding correctness.

Comment: @StepanNovikov yes I got the idea but does this also mean that I should also label the buildings as non-airplane?

Comment: Yes, Berkant, exactly, all non-airplane objects, including building would be marked as belonging to non-airplane class and I would recommend including some or better yet all false detections to a training set of this additional checking ANN we discussing as examples of non-airplane object's class. In my experience where were some objects, especially small, which resemble a bit human faces or animals' faces considered as human faces by Yolo in my case, but easily filtered by this simple additional checking ANN.

Comment: Thanks @StepanNovikov I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: If you are processing a video (because you used frames). Why not leverage the temporal correlation in the videos for filtering out FP? Use some recurrence man

Comment: I have been working on this for just 3 months for real world applications so I am trying to improve my skills on machine learning. Thanks a lot @JVGD